Pure Java implementation for determining off curve Solana public key
I'm trying to work out how to write a Java class that will calculate given a Public key input (byte[32]) whether that point lies on the Edd25519 curve.
package com.lmax.solana4j.util;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Ed25519
{

    // Curve parameters for Ed25519
    private static final BigInteger P = new BigInteger("7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffed", 16);
    private static final BigInteger D = new BigInteger("52036cee2b6ffe738cc740797779e89800700a4d4141d8ab75eb4dca135978a3", 16);
    private static final BigInteger SQRT_CONST = new BigInteger("2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD245A", 16);

    /**
     * Checks if the public key represented by a 32-byte array is on the Ed25519 curve.
     *
     * @param publicKeyBytes The 32-byte array representing the public key.
     * @return true if the point is on the curve, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isOnCurve(final byte[] publicKeyBytes)
    {
        if (publicKeyBytes.length != 32)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Public key must be 32 bytes long");
        }

        // x^2 = u / v where u = y^2 - 1 & v = dy^2 + 1
        byte[] yBytes = publicKeyBytes.clone();
        yBytes[31] &= 0x7F;
        final BigInteger y = new BigInteger(1, yBytes);

        final BigInteger ySquared = y.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, P);
        final BigInteger u = ySquared.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).mod(P);

        final BigInteger v = D.multiply(ySquared).mod(P).add(BigInteger.ONE).mod(P);

        final BigInteger xSquared = u.multiply(v.modInverse(P)).mod(P);

        return rootExists(xSquared);
    }

    private static boolean rootExists(final BigInteger xSquared)
    {
        final BigInteger x = xSquared.modPow(SQRT_CONST, P);

        return x.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, P).equals(xSquared);
    }
}

I've read a few blogs, but the explanations I have found have been confusing (it is rather complicated I suppose).
The problem essentially involves finding x given y. The equation is:
x^2 = u / v where u = y^2 - 1 & v = d * y^2 + 1 (mod p)
Where d is the curve parameter which is -121665 / 1216656 (mod p) and p is the field prime number which is 2^255 - 19.
Now apparently the special properties of this curve allows us to more easily computationally find the square root of a number (mod p) by raising to the power of the SQRT_CONST defined.
My below implementation is the closest I've got based on what I've read, however it does not seem to be giving me the correct output. It reckons known points that lie on the curve actually lie off the curve.
Is somebody able to explain what could be wrong with my implementation and maybe help me with my understanding.
Thanks.

I worked out the solution. It was heavily inspired by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032#section-5.1.3 and realising that the public key input, y coordinate, in fact needs to be flipped, because it's in Little Endian format, but BigInteger interprets byte arrays as Big Endian.
package com.lmax.solana4j.util;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Ed25519
{
    private static final BigInteger P = new BigInteger("7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffed", 16);
    private static final BigInteger D = new BigInteger("52036cee2b6ffe738cc740797779e89800700a4d4141d8ab75eb4dca135978a3", 16);
    private static final BigInteger PM5D8 = P.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(5)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(8));

    /**
     * Checks if the public key represented by a 32-byte array is on the Ed25519 curve.
     *
     * @param publicKeyBytes The 32-byte array representing the public key.
     * @return true if the point is on the curve, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isOnCurve(final byte[] publicKeyBytes)
    {
        if (publicKeyBytes.length != 32)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Public key must be 32 bytes long");
        }

        // elliptic curve equation dx^2y^2 + x^2 = y^2 - 1 (mod P)
        // let x^2 = u/v where u = y^2 - 1 & v = dy^2 + 1 (mod P)
        byte[] yBytes = publicKeyBytes.clone();
        yBytes[31] &= 0x7F;
        // publicKey is in little endian encoding, so we must reverse the byte array before we "math"
        final BigInteger y = new BigInteger(1, reverseByteArray(yBytes));
        final BigInteger y2 = y.multiply(y).mod(P);

        final BigInteger u = y2.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).mod(P);
        final BigInteger v = D.multiply(y2).add(BigInteger.ONE).mod(P);

        final BigInteger x1 = calculateCandidateRoot(u, v);

        return isCandidateRootValid(x1, v, u);
    }

    private static BigInteger calculateCandidateRoot(final BigInteger u, final BigInteger v)
    {
        final BigInteger v3 = v.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, P).multiply(v).mod(P);
        final BigInteger v7 = v3.multiply(v3).multiply(v).mod(P);

        final BigInteger uv3 = u.multiply(v3).mod(P);

        final BigInteger uv7 = u.multiply(v7).mod(P);
        final BigInteger uv7Pm5d8 = uv7.modPow(PM5D8, P);

        // after some transformations, given the properties of the ed25519 curve we can say
        // x^2 = (u/v)
        // x1 = (u/v)^(P+3/8) where x1 is the candidate root
        // x1 = uv^3(uv^7)^(P-5/8)
        return uv3.multiply(uv7Pm5d8).mod(P);
    }

    private static boolean isCandidateRootValid(final BigInteger x1, final BigInteger v, final BigInteger u)
    {
        // given x1 = uv^3(uv^7)^(P-5/8) we can check to see if the candidate root satisfies
        // vx^2 = u (mod P) for x = x1 is a candidate root
        // vx^2 = -u (mod P) for x = x1 is a candidate root
        // if no roots then the point does not lie on the curve
        final BigInteger vx12 = v.multiply(x1.modPow(BigInteger.TWO, P)).mod(P);

        if (vx12.equals(u))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return vx12.equals(u.negate().mod(P));
    }

    private static byte[] reverseByteArray(final byte[] array)
    {
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(array.length);

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            buffer.put(array[i]);
        }

        buffer.flip();

        return buffer.array();
    }
}

